# How do I use reflection to get a list of values of an object's fields that match a particular type?

Tags: c#, reflection

Please note that for conciseness and readability, I've substituted types, fields, and methods that are more simple to work with.

I've defined a boolean property, `personProperty` for a class, `Person`, in which I want the getter, `get{}` to call a private method, `personMethod(int arg)` on each integer field value that's defined in `Person` (in this case `_age`, `_phoneNumber`). It should ignore all other types like `readingList`.

This is so that if I were to add another integer field to `Person` (or modify  or delete any `Person` field names), I would not have to update the definition of `personProperty` which, by design choice, depends on all integer fields of the `Person` class (i.e., it is never the case that the developer will introduce an `int` field that he doesn't want `personMethod` to run against).

```
public Class Person
{
   private int _age;
   public int _phoneNumber;
   // protected int _futureInt;
   Dictionary<string, string> _readingList = new Dictionary<string, string>();

   public bool personProperty
   {
       get
       {
           // ...
           bool personPropertyReturnValue; 
           List<bool> resultList = new List<bool>();
           foreach(int personFieldValue in LISTOFPERSONINTS)
           {
               bool result = personMethod(personFieldValue);
               resultList.Add(result);
           }
           // Do stuff with `resultList` that'll initialize personPropertyReturnValue;
           return personPropertyReturnValue;
       }
   }

    private bool personMethod(int arg)
    {
       bool returnValue = true;
       // Do stuff to initialize `returnValue`
       return returnValue;
    }
}
```

I need to know what I should substitute for `LISTOFPERSONINTS` so that it returns an iterable over the values stored in `_age`, `_phoneNumber` (and all other future `int`, like `_futureInt` defined in `Person`).

Comment: Hopefully you are not storing an actual phone number as an `int`.

Comment: As a side note, please try to follow the standard [naming conventions](https://github.com/ktaranov/naming-convention/blob/master/C%23%20Coding%20Standards%20and%20Naming%20Conventions.md) and unless the names of the fields are just examples, you shouldn't really use `int` for a phone number.

Comment: @John Wu Of course not! The actual class name, method, property and type that I'm working with are more complex.

Comment: If you do this it will be very, very difficult for anyone to understand. Also, suppose you have three `int` fields, and for each one you call `personMethod`. But each of those `int` fields means something different. What meaningful thing can `personMethod` do with an `int` passed to it when it has no idea what that `int` represents? Would it matter if they got passed to `personMethod` in any particular order? If not, why not? Could someone break the code by rearranging the order of fields?

Comment: @ScottHannen Great questions but I think they're more related to the design choice for fields of class `Person` than the _how to_ of accessing the values of a class of a particular type.

Comment: @ScottHannen To address your question, though — the datatype I'm working with, that corresponds to `int` in this example, are similar in meaning so that it makes sense to call some method on them. I can discuss the specifics in another post but I think that discussion fits better in [CodeReviewExchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). The call order does not matter because the result of the method that operates on each `int` does not depend on any previous results. No, changing the declaration order will not cause an error (I've tested).

Comment: @MTV I understand. In this case I just felt almost obligated to mention it. One of the biggest challenges is writing code so that it's easy for other people to understand and maintain. In this case it would be really confusing if fields caused some effect just by existing. It's important to be able to look at something and know what it does and whether it's used. If we see a field that's not used, we delete it. If we change something that shouldn't be changed, the compiler tells us. But in this case none of that would happen - the code would just behave differently in hard-to-understand ways.

Comment: @ScottHannen I was able to test because I tried something that worked. I will post my solution shortly.

Comment: @MTV I agree with Scott as I briefly indicated in my answer and yes, you could try CodeReview once you have a working code (note that on CodeReview, you'll probably need to post a version as close as possible to your real code). That being said, does the answer below answer the particular question you had here or did I misunderstand something?

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed Yes! Nail on the head. In my implementation, I iterated over `FieldInfo` (the resulting type of `.GetType().GetFields()`) and called `aFieldInfo.GetValue()`. I used a `try-except` block to handle where type-conversion fails.

Comment: @MTV You don't need a try-catch for this. You can filter the types either by checking the `FieldType` property as I did below or by calling `OfType<int>()` on the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that using reflection would be better than adjusting your property each time you add a field, but there you go:

```
public class Person
{
    private int _age;
    public int _phoneNumber;
    // protected int _futureInt;
    Dictionary<string, string> _readingList = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    public Person(int age){
        _age = age;
    }

    public bool personProperty
    {
        get
        {
            List<bool> resultList = new List<bool>();
            var intFields = this.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | 
                                                     BindingFlags.NonPublic | 
                                                     BindingFlags.Public)
                                          .Where(f => f.FieldType == typeof(int))
                                          .Select(f => f.GetValue(this)).Cast<int>();
            foreach (int personFieldValue in intFields)
            {
                bool result = personMethod(personFieldValue);
                resultList.Add(result);
            }
            // Do stuff with `resultList` that'll initialize personPropertyReturnValue;
            bool personPropertyReturnValue = resultList.All(b => b);
            return personPropertyReturnValue;
        }
    }

    private bool personMethod(int arg)
    {
        return (arg > 0);
    }
}
```

**Test:**

```
var person1 = new Person(0);
Console.WriteLine(person1.personProperty);   // False

var person2 = new Person(1);
Console.WriteLine(person2.personProperty);   // False

var person3 = new Person(1) { _phoneNumber = 1 };
Console.WriteLine(person3.personProperty);   // True
```

Comment: I'm not very familiar with LINQ so can you help me verify that the expression `.Select(f => f.GetValue(this)).Cast<int>()` simply takes all filtered `FieldInfo` objects and casts them to `int`? This, along with the `.Where` LINQ expression, are important expressions that seem to guarantee that an `InvalidCastException` won't be thrown.

Comment: @MTV That's correct. Except that it doesn't cast the `FieldInfo` objects; it casts the _values_ of the fields returned by the `Select` and `GetValue`. Those values are of type `Object` but they are "boxed `int`s" and that's why we cast them to `int` without worrying about an `InvalidCastException`. Alternatively, you could get rid of the `Where` and use `.Select(f => f.GetValue(this)).OfType<int>();` to directly get the `int` values. I went with the first method because it filters on the `FieldType`s, _not the values_, which allows you to access more than just the values if you wanted to.